# Microchip MTCH6102 - 2 touch surfaces (3x3) on one chip

Tags: microchip, touch-panel

building a project that utilizes Microchip's gesture recognition on their [MTCH6102](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MTCH6102) chip - the device has two touch surfaces (circles, diameter 20mm each, 3x3 conductive mesh outline).

The documentation does not talk about splitting the capacitive mesh to x-number of areas. Do I need two chips, for each touch surface, or there is a way to connect two touch surfaces to one chip AND utilize the on-chip gesture recognition of MTCH6102? It is important to tell which touchsurface recognised the gesture.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you and if it isn't clear, which section or diagram confuses you enough to ask this question on SE.EE?

Comment: The datasheet does not talk about dividing the touch mesh into x-number of sections. It only mentions that you can define how many squares you want to utilise in X and Y axis. Asking SE.EE to see, whether anyone has experienced same challenge and can provide insights.

Comment: That then makes your question a poor fit to this site's Q&A policy: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Can you share which point exactly? I understand you have been here for a long time and definitely helped a lot of people. I highly appreciate it. Your comment, however, does not help really. Yes, I am a noob and yes, I could stop at "documentation does not mention it". I ask these questions because I still don't know what I don't know and this helps to clarify and understand. Is that you really do not have that much time and energy to drop one more line and help me (and definitely others) to move forward? If not, I am sorry. The question was posted to invite sharing experiences with this chip.

Comment: This is a Q&A site and not a site to solicit opinions. Questions that seek opinions are not a good fit. I have not voted to close your question BTW. I can't help you further with this.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to respond again. The Q&A Policy, that you really like, literally mentions that questions that invite sharing experiences are constructive subjective questions and these are allowed. Why haven't you voted to close my question? Please close it, if it is not supposed to be here. This does not make any sense, it does not move us forward in any way. What should I think? They tell me the question is dumb, but don't want to take it down? Why? If the question should not be here downvote it, flag it, destroy it. I will appreciate it, because I am all for constructive SE.EE.

Comment: I’ve not down voted because it’s borderline between soliciting opinions. Others may answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting [answer](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1036747.aspx) from Microchip forum, if anyone would stumble upon this topic:

> MTCH6102 only handles one surface, so you will need two MTCH6102 for two touch surfaces.